# Camera not opening on ported rom

Tags: cyanogenmod, 6.0-marshmallow

I'm porting CyanogenMod13 for the UMi Super and camera isn't working.Can anyone tell me what it means and how to fix? This is the error that comes up in logcat, when trying to open camera:

```
08-18 15:34:37.983   313   313 E MtkCam/devicemgr: [getPlatform] dlopen: libcam_platform.so error=dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "_Z9SmoothCCMRK10AWB_GAIN_TiiR26ISP_NVRAM_MULTI_CCM_STRUCTRN11NSIspTuning15ISP_NVRAM_CCM_TER16ISP_CCM_WEIGHT_Tii" referenced by "/system/lib/libfeatureio.so"... (getPlatform){#96:vendor/mediatek/proprietary/hardware/mtkcam/legacy/module_hal/devicemgr/CamDeviceManagerBase.platform.cpp}
08-18 15:34:37.983   313   313 E MtkCam/devicemgr: [openDeviceLocked] No Platform (openDeviceLocked){#386:vendor/mediatek/proprietary/hardware/mtkcam/legacy/module_hal/devicemgr/CamDeviceManagerBase.openDevice.cpp}
08-18 15:34:37.983   313   313 E CameraClient: Could not open camera 0: -19
08-18 15:34:37.983   313   313 E CameraClient: initialize: Camera 0: unable to initialize device: No such device (-19)
08-18 15:34:37.983   313   313 E CameraService: connectHelper: Could not initialize client from HAL module.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Propably you are trying to use your device's camera with an incompatible lib. So you have to determine your device camera type and find a compatible lib to controll it. After you should use this lib with the camera app.

Comment: The problem was with libfeatureio.so, I forgot to port that. Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: I upvoted, but users under 15rep don't change the publicly displayed post score. Thank you again tho.